# ObjectDisposedException was unhandled: Safe handle has been closed at program end

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, console-application, objectdisposedexception

I have a .NET 4 C# console application. It pulls data from our IBM i and sends it to our internet SQL Server. It works perfect until it ends, I get the following error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled   Message=Safe handle has
>   been closed   Source=mscorlib   ObjectName=""   StackTrace:
>          at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousRelease()
>          at System.Threading.RegisteredWaitHandleSafe.Finalize()   InnerException:

My program code is:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Begin: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        SystemCodeController sc = new SystemCodeController();
        sc.SyncSystemCodes();
        ParkingTicketController pt = new ParkingTicketController();
        pt.SyncParkingTickets();
        EmailHelper.SendSuccessEmail();
        System.Console.WriteLine("End: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

In the console, I see the begin time and the end time. So I know the final line does get executed. What am I forgetting or not doing that I should be?

**Update**: The Sync* methods pull data from the IBM into an object then uses entity framework to insert the records into the database.

```
public void SyncParkingTickets()
{
    ptr.ClearTable();
    ptr.InsertNewCitation(ibmI.GetAllCitations());
    ptr.SaveChanges();
}

public void InsertNewCitation(IEnumerable<ParkingTicket> citations)
{
    foreach (ParkingTicket citation in citations)
    {
        InsertNewCitation(citation);
    }
}

public void InsertNewCitation(ParkingTicket citation)
{
    db.AddToParkingTickets(citation);
}

public IEnumerable<ParkingTicket> GetAllCitations()
{
    SystemCodeRepository scr = new SystemCodeRepository();

    //  Create SQL statement

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (iDB2Connection conn = new iDB2Connection(_connString))
    {
        using (iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(sb.ToString(), conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (iDB2DataAdapter da = new iDB2DataAdapter(cmd)) { da.Fill(dt); }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    #region Fill object from DataTable
    var citations = from i in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    select new ParkingTicket
                    {
                        // Fill object
                    };
    #endregion

    return citations;
}
```

All of the methods operate similar to this one.

Comment: What do the `Sync*` family of calls do? Can we see that code? I'll bet its leaking a WaitHandle.

Comment: I don't know what `WaitHandle` is, so I am probably only indirectly using it.

Comment: I've tracked it down to the IBM drivers, I've updated my answer to reflect this and the likely fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little bit of [Googling reveals some scattered reports](http://www.google.com/search?q=iDB2Connection%20ObjectDisposedException) of the same error when using the iDB2Connection family of database access methods. Evidently IBM is relying on .Net 1.1 handling of EventHandles which changed in the move to .Net 2.0 [per this Connect article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115170/ibm-iseries-client-access-v5r3-issue).

It seems the only reprieve is to update to the latest version of the IBM drivers (using the S21917 service pack for 5.3 or SI37892 for 5.4 as you note).

---

Are you calling `Close()` on the `SafeWaitHandle` for a `WaitHandle`?

```
WaitHandle wh = ...;

wh.SafeWaitHandle.Close(); // will throw ObjectDisposedException
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.safewaithandle.aspx):

> When you assign a new value to the SafeWaitHandle property, the previous handle will be closed when the previous SafeWaitHandle object is collected. Do not manually close the handle, because this results in an ObjectDisposedException when the SafeWaitHandle attempts to close the handle.

Comment: Woah, thats a bad implementation. Calling a `Dispose` method resulting in `ObjectDisposedException`?!

Comment: @ordag: actually the ObjectDisposedException is being thrown from code, usually in another thread, which is relying on the disposed event handle!

Comment: Okay... I am using 5.4 not 5.3 for client access. I am downloading the latest patch anyway. I have a feeling this will just push us faster to the latest version of iSeries Access. Which is a PITA. ALL projects have to be upgraded at once because you can't have multiple versions of the driver installed at once.

Comment: Upgrading to my iSeries Access V5R4 to [SI37892](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/as400/products/clientaccess/win32/v5r4m0/servicepack/si37892/) seemed to have worked. Funny, I thought I was on the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Are any of your types [Disposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx)? Try disposing all of your disposable resources before exiting the application.

Comment: That was my first thought after posting. I made sure none of my code has `IDisposable`. That didn't help. I am now making sure every object I touch has `.Dispose()` included.

Comment: @MikeWills: adding `IDisposable` doesn't magically fix the problem with `SafeHandle` usage. You need to look into your code for usage of `SafeHandle` or its derived classes. Likely some code related to a WaitHandle is at fault.

Comment: Like I said above, I don't know what 'WaitHandle' is, so I am probably only indirectly using it

Answer (score 0):

I have an equal situation. The problem there is that a `P/Invoke` call in `SafeHandle.ReleaseHandle` does some magic and calls `System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)`, which tries to do something with the `SafeHandle` after it was disposed.

Its not your own `SafeHandle` implementation isn't it? Otherwise you could have tried extending `CriticalHandle` instead.

Comment: No, I haven't done anything like that. Is this a known bug? Is there a work-around if there is? I would hate to have problems when implementing this live.

Comment: I have the same error (different app of course). But after looking at it again I think I was wrong. See my edit above.